# Cannot create table in Phpmyadmin interface only

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed the new version of XAMMP v3.2.1 and update my Phpmyadmin  to Phpmyadmin 4.4.2

I can create database but I cannot create a table using Phpmyadmin interface, it display this message like this

> **Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Application_Octetstream_Download in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\plugins\transformations\Application_Octetstream_Download.class.php on line 42**

*Note: I try to create table in other IDE(like MySQL Server), it successfully create and reflect to Phpmyadmin*